# Blazor - Value saved in TimeSpan doesn't go through HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, httpclient, timespan

I am using this class (representing goal) as model:

```
public class Goal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<GoalDay> Days { get; set; } = new List<GoalDay>();

    public bool IsAllDayGenerated { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateGenerated { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LengthTimeGenerated { get; set; }
    public int TotalValue { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Method in service sending data:

```
    public async Task AddGoal(Goal goal)
    {
        var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync<Goal>("api/goal", goal);

        if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            _toastService.ShowError(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        else
        {
            _toastService.ShowSuccess(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
```

Method in controller receiving data:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateGoal(Goal goal)
    {
        var user = await _utilityService.GetUser();
        goal.UserId = user.Id;

        _context.Goals.Add(goal);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok("Goal added days:" + goal.Days.Count);
    }
```

When I send data using HttpPost to server value saved in TimeSpan (in variable LengthTimeGenerated ) is there. In the upper part of picture can be seen printscreen of network traffic.
But afterward in controller data are gone.  In the lower part of the picture can be seen printscreen of model zero value of the same variable in controller.

[image: Value is gone]

Comment: You should show us the code used to both send and receive the data - otherwise no-one could possibly know what is wrong - they could guess, but that wouldn't help anyone else reading this in the future.

Comment: tnx, code of responsible methods added.

Comment: Are you on the latest bits? `TimeSpan` serialization was added to `System.Text.Json` (used by Blazor) with version 6.0. Your screenshot is showing the value not serialized correctly.

Comment: As you can see, the Timespan is not correctly serialized. Google how to serialize Timespan using System.Text.Json. I will need custom converter, which is pretty easy.

Comment: I am with version 5. If version 6.0 could help maybe is time to go for it. I will also look for TimeSpan serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the classic case of the camel case changes in the `System.Text.Json` compared to Newtownsoft. (`System.Text.Json` is case sensitive by default)

Try adding serialization option to use camel case.

```
private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _jsonSerializerOptions = new() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

  // usage
  public async Task AddGoal(Goal goal)
    {
        var result = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync<Goal>("api/goal", goal, _jsonSerializerOptions);
    //... etc
    }
```

Other example of usage:

```
var myParsedObject = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<SomeResponseType>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), _jsonSerializerOptions);
```

Comment: tnx for suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't help.